# Cannot get list of photo URL from album ID in SkyDrive

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

I am developing iOS application,i am using **Live Connect API** in order to get photos from SkyDrive.
I can able to access all the album details but i cannot get the list of photos URL from album.

First, I'm doing `@"me/albums"` to get the albums,

//here is the code to get the particular image

```
-(void) downloadFile
{
[self.liveClient downloadFromPath:@"file.95d463b9efcca0e1.95D463B9EFCCA0E1!113/content" 
                         delegate:self];
}
- (void) liveOperationSucceeded:(LiveOperation *)operation
{
LiveDownloadOperation * downloadOperation = (LiveDownloadOperation *)operation;
UIImage *downloadedPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:downloadOperation.data];
imageView.image = downloadedPicture;
}
```

How do i get the photo url (downloadFromPath:) from album's id?

Does anyone know how to get list of photos from album.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all photos in an album by using ALBUM_ID/photos. The iOS documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659717.aspx) has more information about working with albums.